# PHP SESSION does not allow to open the page if you are not logged in

Tags: php, authentication, session, redirect

I have created a registration and login. The logged in user can browse all pages, the offline user should be able to open only certain pages. I have made it possible for the user to be redirected to the login page if they try to log in to the home page (it should only be accessed if they are logged in), but I want the user to be able to open the Help page but it is redirected to the login page. How do I prevent certain pages from being redirected to a login page if the user is not logged in?

I have this code for redirecting to login page:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

// Patikriname ar vartotojas prisijungęs, jeigu ne, nukeliame į prisijungimas.php puslapį
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Pirmiausia privalote prisijungti";
    header('location: prisijungimas.php');
}
// Jeigu vartotojas atsijungia, nukeliame į prisijungimas.php puslapį
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: prisijungimas.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Just check what page they're on before redirecting? What is the challenge you're facing with that?

Comment: You should make a list of pages that are NOT for members. Do not check on those pages if user logged on or not.

Answer (score -1):

Suggestion : Check into your help page, remove if you have set any session restriction check like your other pages.

Comment: This is something more suitable to be a comment not an answer.